# Failing QUnit tests using FixtureAdapter depending on the test order

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I created a few JSFiddle's to demonstrate the problem. The app breaks when testing and I have not been able to find out why. There are three models "Subscriber", "Line" and "LineActivity". When loading a subscriber index route, I render the lines associated with the subscriber. Then the next test loads the subscribers line activities route. In the qunit test the line activities do not render, which causes the test to fail.

If I reverse the test order, testing line activities before testing the subscriber index route all of the tests pass. Is this a symptom of a problem with my Application? My tests? Or a bug in QUnit/Ember? Thanks for looking.

Application with failing tests
http://jsfiddle.net/webguy/gNpnh/6/

```
test 'index', ->
  visit('/subscribers/1').then ->
    ok($('#subscriber-lines tbody tr:visible').length, "subscriber lines rows are rendered")

test 'show', ->
  visit('/subscribers/1/line/1').then ->
    ok($('#recent-activity tbody tr:visible').length, "recent activity rows are rendered")
```

Application with passing tests
http://jsfiddle.net/webguy/gNpnh/5/

```
test 'show', ->
  visit('/subscribers/1/line/1').then ->
    ok($('#recent-activity tbody tr:visible').length, "recent activity rows are rendered")

test 'index', ->
  visit('/subscribers/1').then ->
    ok($('#subscriber-lines tbody tr:visible').length, "subscriber lines rows are rendered")
```